# Why can't I get rid of my caret in my dropdown button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that when clicked dropdown a menu. The button is a chat icon (fontawesome) and next to it I get a caret. I can't get rid of the caret. This is what I'm doing (I'm using Bootstrap 4):

```css
.message-notification-chat-icon-mobile .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn dropdown-toggle ml-auto message-notification-chat-icon-mobile" type="button" id="dropdownTopMenuMessageNotification" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="messageNotificationIcon">
        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
    </button>
    
    
  
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: can't see caret

Comment: I corrected my code. Now you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the class `dropdown-toggle` and it works. If for any reason you can't remove it, just do it with the css you wrote, changing

```
.message-notification-chat-icon-mobile .dropdown-toggle::after {
```

to

```
.message-notification-chat-icon-mobile.dropdown-toggle::after {
```

See both approaches in the following code:

```css
.message-notification-chat-icon-mobile.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
>

<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<button
  class="btn ml-auto message-notification-chat-icon-mobile"
  type="button"
  id="dropdownTopMenuMessageNotification"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
  id="messageNotificationIcon"
>
  Dropdown 1 <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
</button>

<button
  class="btn dropdown-toggle ml-auto message-notification-chat-icon-mobile"
  type="button"
  id="dropdownTopMenuMessageNotification"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
  id="messageNotificationIcon"
>
  Dropdown 2 <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Just removing the `dropdown-toggle` did the trick.